# Mailto: via CSS stopped working years ago

Tags: css, mailto

Clicking on the `mailicon.gif button` (or typing the 'm' key) used open the standard mail program with the `To:` and `Subject:` fields already filled out, but this has stopped working.

html:

```
<A HREF="#" class="myMail" accesskey="m"><img src="mailicon.gif"></a>
```

css:

```
a.myMail:active {background:url('mailto:my.address@xmail.com?subject=Some Feedback');}
```

Nowadays it only adds the `#` to the url in the browser-addressline, screen stays the same and nothing more happens. How can I restore the old behavior?

Comment: I do _not_ get why its assumed that a _layout_ declaration would be defining an _interaction_. Where did you even dig up this code? I don't believe it could have _ever_ worked...

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but I'm sorry, can't recall where I found this years ago (it was some forum on the Internet, not StackOverflow), and I'm pretty sure it was working. Still have those old html+css files and wanted to use it in my updated website.

Comment: Try not to, this seems very bad if it even works. Use @dominictobias answer instead. It makes much more sense to have it in your html or javascript!

Answer (score 1):

Your mailto should be defined on the href (the link), you linked to just `#`, css is for styling:

```
<a href="mailto:my.address@xmail.com?subject=Some%20Feedback"><img src="mailicon.gif"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but yes, I know that is the 'proper' way, but I just didn't want the email address in the html code. Another reason is that I had many small html files, and just defining a 'myMail' class was easier for maintenance, e.g. in case the email address changed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for your remarks, and having the ‘mailto’ in the html in principle is the proper way to go if you have only 1 or 2 mailaddresses.
I probably over-simplified my question by just showing the 2 lines of coding. The problem I faced was a bit larger, i.e. not one email address but several. Therefore, a long time ago I implemented what I specified in those 2 lines of coding. In reality I had more than 50 html files and x classes: class=”Anne” class=“Boris”, class=”Charlie” and so on.
Having the mail-addresses in the one css file, used by all html files, made life easy, and it did work, I’m sure of that.

In the meantime css and browsers have evolved, matured and some rules have changed, that’s probably why it is not working anymore.
Nevermind, instead of those 50 html files I now have only 1 html file, 1 javascript file and many JSON files, each containing a short description of a number of photographs. One of the items in there is the name of the photographer.
This name is displayed as an image below the picture, and when one clicks on that image, the program tries to open the default mail-program to send a mail.
It now works as follows in the javascript file:

```
var emailinfo = '@domain.com?subject=Website%20Fotos%20Feedback';

function HandleKeyDown(e) {
  ....
  else if (e.keyCode == 77) {   // m  keyboard shortcut to start mail-program
    SendEmail();
  ]
}

function SendEmail() {
  if (!copyrightname == '') { 
    window.open('mailto:'+copyrightname.toLowerCase()+emailinfo);
  } 
}

function LoadText(elt) {
  ....
  if (elt.copyright) {
    copyrightname = elt.copyright;  // used later when 'm' is clicked or copyrightmsg is clicked.
    temp = '<img src="icons/cr_' + elt.copyright + '.gif" title="Click here to send a mail.">';
    $("#copyright").html(temp);     // show the image below the picture
  }
  else {copyrightname = '';}
  ....
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keydown(HandleKeyDown);
  $("#copyright").click(SendEmail);
  ....
}
```

For the time being it works in FF.
IE gives warning that mailprog was not correctly defined, Chrome opens a blank window.  These of course are different problems so I’m gonna work on those now.

Hope you now see why I can't have the complete name in the only html file I have.

See it working (in FF) on wijchman.com and then click on the (big) icon with the small pictures.

Thanks for reading so far and your suggestions.